# Enough of this charade! A common property puzzle

Tags: pattern, english, language, word-sequence, tribond

Below are three sets of three words. Each word shares a common linguistic property. The words in each set share a nested property. Identify the properties and explain.

> Lift
>   Beams
>   Destroy

> Gas
>   Lapse
>   Successor

> Compose
>   Correct
>   Custom

This appears to be harder than I had intended, so I'll start providing hints.

**Hint 1:**

> There are two stages to this puzzle. To uncover stage two, it may help to read aloud. There's more in what you'll hear than in what you'll see.

**Hint 2:**

> Some of these words have multiple meanings, but this puzzle only focuses on one. To hopefully weed out some red herrings in future answers, here is a list of which part of speech each word is meant to be:
>  **Lift**: Verb
>  **Beams**: Plural noun
>  **Destroy**: Verb
>  **Gas**: Noun
>  **Lapse**: Verb
>  **Successor**: Noun
>  **Compose**: Verb
>  **Correct**: Adjective
>  **Custom**: Noun

Comment: Looks difficult. Is the title a hint?

Comment: @JLee A very slight one. It's a hint wrapped in further riddle, but not technically part of the puzzle itself.

Comment: So, if I understand this correctly, all 9 words are related, and then each group has its own, distinct, relationship?

Comment: @tfitzger All 9 words have the same general property. The words in each group share the property in a more specific scenario. If this is still unclear I can try to describe it better, and update the question accordingly. I am very sure that there is a unique and recognizable solution, but it may require an "aha!" moment in order to find it.

Comment: Could I ask for the definition of a linguistic property? Or would this give too much away?

Comment: By "linguistic property" I mean that the property relating these terms is based on aspects of language, and has nothing to do with math, numbering, cryptography, or anything of the sort. In other words, I'm not trying to trick anyone; the words presented represent exactly what you would think at first glance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Each set shares words that have:

> synonyms that produce a set of [heterographs](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterograph) (words with different meanings and spellings, but the same pronunciation).

Lift, Beams, Destroy:

> Raise, Rays, Raze

Gas, Lapse, Successor:

> Air, Err, Heir

Compose, Correct, Custom:

> Write, Right, Rite

Comment: The word you're looking for is [homophones](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define:homophone)

Comment: @Joe - Ha, of course (although technically they're [heterographs](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterograph)).

Comment: **Technically** they're both :P All heterographs are homophones, but not all homophones are heterographs ^_^

Comment: Was going for homophones, but great job!

Answer (score 3):

An over all common property:

> Transformation

Set 1 property:

> Building - **Lifting** support **beams** or **destroying** structures
>
> (From nothing transforms to something, or something to nothing)

Set 2 property:

> Chemistry - Reaction of **Gas** over a **Lapse** of time into a **Successor** Gas
>
> (From one gas composite transforms to another gas composite)

Set 3 property:

> Art - **Composing** music, **Correcting** mistakes in it, and **Customizing** other music
>
> (From imagination/creation, transforms into art)

If some more sets were to be added, I think it could be relate to:

> Biology, math or Physics

Creating a over all theme that appears about:

> Schooling paths: Engineering (building), Chemistry, Art

Comment: +1 for the amount of thought you've put into this. This isn't what I'm going for, but it's very impressive. The correct answer is far less complex.

Answer (score -1):

I have no clue if this is part of it, but

> The groups of words increment in syllable count

What I mean is:

> Lift - 1
> Beams - 1
> Destroy - 2
> Total: 4
> Gas - 1
> Lapse - 1
> Successor - 3
> Total: 5
> Compose - 2
> Correct - 2
> Custom - 2
> Total: 6

Comment: That's not related to the puzzle, but it is a neat coincidence.

Answer (score -3):

Well, I don't think this is the intended solution but I think it's technically correct.

The linguistic property they all share:

> They are all English words

1st set

> They are all English words that are verbs

2nd set

> They are all English words having the letter S

3rd set

> They are all English words beginning with the letter C